# How to print out log history for AnkhSVN in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

I have build a project using AnkhSVN subversion in Visual Studio. I will like to print all the log messages in a text file or word document. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible yet. You can do this with the command line tools, or with TortoiseSVN